# RM one-way ANOVA or Friedman test

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, repeated-measures, sample-size, friedman-test

I here my question. I'm testing with n=6 animals in 6 different situations. It's repeated measures because all 6 animals did the same tests. When I do the column statistics to see if the distribution of the groups is normal some test say no some yes, about some groups. But there is allways one group that is not normally distributed. Or the test say the sample seize is too small to even aply the test.  Should I go for a Friedmantest if just as 1 of the 6 groups is not normally distributed? Is it for friedmantest also so that the sample seize n should be always bigger than than the group size k, like in the ANOVA. If so any good reference?? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: please state  your objective ?

Comment: Friedman test is used for unreplicated complete block design.  That is, you have one observation for each combination of Animal and Situation.  I don't know of any reference that specifically mentions the permissible ratio of n to k, but some examples in Conover, Practical Nonparametric Statistics, 3rd ed. have e.g. 5 blocks and 4 treatments, or 3 blocks and 6 treatments.

Comment: To test for normality:  Do the ANOVA; find the 36 residuals; then test the residuals for normality. // Recommendations for sample sizes may have to do with ensuring sufficient power. Of course, if data are determined carefully, it's almost always better to have more. For example, you'd have better power if you tested each animal _twice_ at each condition. If animals are extremely variable, that may mask differences in condition so you couldn't reject your main null hypothesis. But if residuals are close to normal w/ stable var, I don't see a problem analyzing your data with block design ANOVA.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an analysis of some data that were collected according to a design
much like you are considering. Such models are sometimes called a two-way ANOVA without replication, a (complete, unreplicated) block design (as in
@SalMangiafico's Comment), or (one type of) repeated measures design. [A one-way ANOVA is something altogether different.] The
analysis below, from Minitab statistical software, is similar to what you
may encounter in your study.

**Data.** We use data from a wine judging event reported in Amerine and Roessler (1976): *Wines: Their Sensory Evaluation,* Freeman, San Francisco. Each of four wines was tasted by each of five judges. Scores are sums of several components judges
were asked to consider.

```
Judge \ Wine    1      2      3      4   

    1          13     18     15     10    
    2          15     16     12     11    
    3          14     15     11      9    
    4          12     17     13     10    
    5          13     19     12     12
```

**ANOVA Model for Block design.** Based on the model $Y_{ij} = \mu + W_i + J_j + e_{ij},$ where 
$e_{ij} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma),$ for $i=1,\dots,4$ wines $j=1,\dots,5$ judges, here is the ANOVA table:

```
Two-way ANOVA: Score versus Wine, Judge 

Source  DF      SS       MS      F      P
Wine     3  112.95  37.6500  21.72  0.000
Judge    4    8.80   2.2000   1.27  0.335
Error   12   20.80   1.7333
Total   19  142.55
```

The null hypothesis that wines are judged equal in quality is rejected and *post hoc* tests can be done to determine the pattern of differences. 
For example, it seems clear that the difference between wines 2 and 4 is significant.

There is no
evidence that judges differ significantly in the way they evaluated the wines (more harshly
or leniently).

***Diagnostics:*** Scores are sums of several components judges were asked to consider, and so one
might hope the residuals would be normally distributed. However, it seems that
there are not enough extreme residuals in each direction for them to be
consistent with sampling from a normal distribution.
A normal probability plot of the residuals with an Anderson-Darling test of
normality (normality just barely rejected at the 5% level):

[image]

I am not sure departure from normality is sufficiently extreme to cast doubt
on the finding of significant differences among wines. A plot of residuals against fits does not show any systematic nonrandomness or difficulty with
unequal variances.

[image]

**Nonparametric block design.** A Friedman test of the same data gives results below:

```
Friedman Test: Score versus Wine blocked by Judge 

S = 12.78  DF = 3  P = 0.005
S = 13.04  DF = 3  P = 0.005 (adjusted for ties)
```

Notice that the Friedman procedure provides only a test whether wines differ (not whether judges differ). 
Paired differences between wines could be assessed by several Wilcoxon signed rank
tests, using the Bonferroni method to control the 'family error rate'. With only five judges, paired Wilcoxon tests may have poor power, but every judge prefers wine 2 to wine 4 by at least 5 points, so those two wines must be significantly different.

All 20 scores lie between 9 an 19, so necessarily there are a few ties, but
it seems not enough of them to spoil results of the Friedman test.

*Note:* Amerine  & Roessler p145 show the same ANOVA as above. Also, they get Tukey HSD 2.54 for significant differences among the four wines. With wine averages
17.9(2), 13.4(1), 12.6(3), 10.4(4), Wine 2 is significantly higher than all others, and Wine 4 lowest, but not *significantly* lower than Wine 3. They do not show results of the Friedman test.